# Why do my grid-rows span 1 row when I have set them to span 2, instead?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a question related to grid-row and span in the below code:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.item {
  padding: 3rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.item:first-child {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  background: blueviolet;
}

.item:nth-child(9) {
  grid-column: 2 / span 3;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8</div>
  <div class="item">Item 9</div>
  <div class="item">Item 10</div>
  <div class="item">Item 11</div>
  <div class="item">Item 12</div>
  <div class="item">Item 13</div>
  <div class="item">Item 14</div>
  <div class="item">Item 15</div>
</div>
```

Here's the output?:

[image]

As we can see in the output screenshot, Item1 spans just 1 row and item 9 spans only 1 row, but in the CSS style I have provided a row span of 2 for both item1 and item9. Can someone please explain the reason?

Comment: if you add grid-gap you will clearly see the issue like detailed in the below answers

Answer (score 4):

### A bit of background first.

You have no explicit rows defined. All rows in your grid are implicit.

*From the spec:*

> [§ 7.1. The Explicit
>   Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#explicit-grids)
>
> The three properties `grid-template-rows`, `grid-template-columns`,
>   and `grid-template-areas` together define the explicit grid of a grid
>   container.

In other words, because you're not using `grid-template-rows` or `grid-template-areas`, the grid has no defined rows (i.e., explicit rows), and rows are created as needed (i.e., implicit rows).

*Continuing from the spec section above*:

> The final grid may end up larger due to grid items placed outside the
>   explicit grid; in this case implicit tracks will be created, these
>   implicit tracks will be sized by the `grid-auto-rows` and
>   `grid-auto-columns` properties.

*Okay, but why isn't the `span 2` expanding the grid area across two rows?*

Actually, it is.

---

### Answer

The grid spec has a rule that instructs the browser to *always create one grid line in the relevant axis when `grid-template-columns`, `grid-template-rows` and `grid-template-areas` are not present*.

Again from section 7.1. above:

> If these properties don’t define any explicit tracks the explicit grid
>   still contains one grid line in each axis.

Hence, a close look at your grid (in this case, using [Firefox's Inspector tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_grid_layouts)) will reveal that `span 2` is working fine, but there's an extra line that has been created, so it only appears to be failing.

[image]

Notice how row lines 2 and 3 are superimposed.

An easy fix would be to define a height for the implicit rows. This overrides the default `auto` height, which causes the row to fully collapse when empty.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px; /* new */
}

.item {
  padding: 3rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.item:first-child {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  background: blueviolet;
}

.item:nth-child(9) {
  grid-column: 2 / span 3;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8</div>
  <div class="item">Item 9</div>
  <div class="item">Item 10</div>
  <div class="item">Item 11</div>
  <div class="item">Item 12</div>
  <div class="item">Item 13</div>
  <div class="item">Item 14</div>
  <div class="item">Item 15</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would add that `grid-auto-rows: 1fr` is probably the exact value the OP is looking for.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I would agree, if there was a defined height on the container. But I generally avoid using free-space distribution when there isn't any free space. That's not to say your solution wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: (Also, I did see your note about [contributing to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59919727/3597276). I haven't yet had the time to go through it carefully. I'll hopefully get to it soon.)

Comment: True but I suspect the OP want to have equal row height so `1fr` will do the job here (no rush for the other question ;) )

Answer (score 1):

In your `.grid` styles block, you will need to include an explicit `grid-template-rows` style declaration.

Once `.grid` *explicitly* contains more than one row, your styling for **Item 1** and **Item 9** will work.

**e.g.**

```
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
```

or, as *@Paulie_D* suggests:

```
grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1fr);
```

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.item {
  padding: 3rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.item:first-child {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  background: blueviolet;
}

.item:nth-child(9) {
  grid-column: 2 / span 3;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8</div>
  <div class="item">Item 9</div>
  <div class="item">Item 10</div>
  <div class="item">Item 11</div>
  <div class="item">Item 12</div>
  <div class="item">Item 13</div>
  <div class="item">Item 14</div>
  <div class="item">Item 15</div>
</div>
```